# JAVA - Variable is always null

Tags: java, android, variables, null

I've made this code where the variable `DEVICE` will change if a file exist or not. So i have made this code but the variable `DEVICE` is always null

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    String DEVICE;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        apply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.apply);
        apply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    checktypezip(DEVICE);
                    while (DEVICE == null){
                        Log.v("Check","Check non completo");
                    }
            }
        });

    }

    public void checktypezip(String string){
        String percorso = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/BAC/.unzipfile/";

        File normalzip = new File (percorso+"desc.txt");
        File flashzip = new File (percorso+"/system/media/bootanimation.zip");
        File samsung = new File (percorso+"/bootsamsung.qmg");
        File flashsamsung = new File (percorso+"/system/media/bootsamsung.qmg");
        String disp;

        disp=string;
        if (normalzip.exists()){
            disp = "Normal";
            string=disp;
        }
        else if (flashzip.exists()){
            disp = "Flashnormal";
            string=disp;
        }
        else if (samsung.exists()){
            disp = "Samsung";
            string=disp;
        }
        else if (flashsamsung.exists()){
            disp = "Samsungflash";
            string=disp;
        }
        else
        {
            disp = "Unknown";
            string=disp;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: that's because you never giva a value to is.

Comment: You are not updating `DEVICE` in the `checktypezip` methods because `string` is not a pointer. `string = "foo"` will not update `DEVICE`. PS : this is a nice infinite loop ;)

Comment: Add return type to checktypezip or remove param from it and access member variable directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java uses 'pass by value'. This means that the **value** of `DEVICE` is passed to your function, not the reference. Although you are assigning a value to the parameter `string`, it will never be assigned to `DEVICE`.

You must return the value of `disp` from your function and assign it to `DEVICE`

Define your function like this

```
public String checktypezip()
```

and call it like this

```
DEVICE = checktypezip();
```

At the end of `checktypezip`, you must add `return disp`

**On a side note:**

```
while (DEVICE == null){
    Log.v("Check","Check non completo");
}
```

This will block your main thread indefinitely and cause an ANR after 5 seconds. I would suggest replacing `while` with `if`